# some setting has changed in visual studio 6.0 so that i am not able to execute my project .what are the necessary settings?

Tags: visual-c++

i have changed some setting in vc++ 6.0 as i am new to this environment please help me in finding it out what are necessary settings?I am not even able to compile my code.Example errors:

```
error C2065: 'EnumProcesses' : undeclared identifier
2.error C2065: 'LPTSTR' : undeclared identifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
#include <windows.h>
```

If your cpp files all start with #include "stdafx.h" then put the #include  into the stdafx.h file.